no decode delegate for this image format `JPEG'
I am using Alpine to build a docker container. After recent updates I get the error message:
no decode delegate for this image format `JPEG'

When I list the supported formats JPEG seems to miss:
$ magick -list format | grep JP
             see part 5 which describes the image encoding (RLE, JPEG, JPEG-LS),
             and supplement 61 which adds JPEG-2000 encoding.
      JNG* PNG       rw-   JPEG Network Graphics
      PGX* PGX       rw-   JPEG 2000 uncompressed format

The images I want to handle have the ending '.jpg'
The following version is installed:
$ convert --version
Version: ImageMagick 7.1.1-32 Q16-HDRI aarch64 22207 https://imagemagick.org
Copyright: (C) 1999 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: https://imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI Modules OpenMP(4.5)
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo fftw fontconfig freetype gslib heic jng jpeg jxl lcms ltdl lzma pangocairo png ps raw rsvg tiff webp x xml zlib zstd

That looks like jpeg is included!
What I am doing is using the Imagick php class in php 8.2.23, especially the methods getImageWidth() and getImageHeight().
If I am using identify or convert directly in the console it works.
The width and height are used to calculate the ratio and create a pdf with Dompdf, which contains the image file.
Any idea what could cause this error?
Does JNG include jpg/jpeg images?
Edit: output of phpinfo:
$ php -i | grep agick
imagick
imagick module => enabled
imagick module version => 3.7.0
imagick classes => Imagick, ImagickDraw, ImagickPixel, ImagickPixelIterator, ImagickKernel
Imagick compiled with ImageMagick version => ImageMagick 7.1.1-32 Q16-HDRI x86_64 22207 https://imagemagick.org
Imagick using ImageMagick library version => ImageMagick 7.1.1-32 Q16-HDRI x86_64 22207 https://imagemagick.org
ImageMagick copyright => (C) 1999 ImageMagick Studio LLC
ImageMagick release date => 2024-05-05
ImageMagick number of supported formats:  => 198
ImageMagick supported formats => 3G2, 3GP, AAI, APNG, ART, ASHLAR, AVI, AVS, BAYER, BAYERA, BGR, BGRA, BGRO, BMP, BMP2, BMP3, BRF, CAL, CALS, CANVAS, CAPTION, CIN, CIP, CLIP, CMYK, CMYKA, CUBE, CUR, CUT, DATA, DCM, DCX, DDS, DFONT, DOT, DPX, DXT1, DXT5, EPS2, EPS3, EPT, EPT2, EPT3, FARBFELD, FAX, FF, FILE, FITS, FL32, FLV, FRACTAL, FTP, FTS, FTXT, G3, G4, GIF, GIF87, GRADIENT, GRAY, GRAYA, GV, HALD, HDR, HISTOGRAM, HRZ, HTM, HTML, HTTP, HTTPS, ICB, ICO, ICON, INFO, INLINE, IPL, ISOBRL, ISOBRL6, JNG, JNX, JSON, KERNEL, LABEL, M2V, M4V, MAC, MAP, MASK, MAT, MATTE, MIFF, MKV, MNG, MONO, MOV, MP4, MPC, MPEG, MPG, MSL, MTV, MVG, NULL, ORA, OTB, OTF, PAL, PALM, PAM, PATTERN, PBM, PCD, PCDS, PCL, PCT, PCX, PDB, PES, PFA, PFB, PFM, PGM, PGX, PHM, PICON, PICT, PIX, PLASMA, PNG, PNG00, PNG24, PNG32, PNG48, PNG64, PNG8, PNM, PPM, PS2, PS3, PSB, PSD, PWP, QOI, RADIAL-GRADIENT, RAS, RGB, RGB565, RGBA, RGBO, RGF, RLA, RLE, SCR, SCT, SFW, SGI, SHTML, SIX, SIXEL, SPARSE-COLOR, STEGANO, STRIMG, SUN, TEXT, TGA, THUMBNAIL, TILE, TIM, TM2, TTC, TTF, TXT, UBRL, UBRL6, UIL, UYVY, VDA, VICAR, VID, VIFF, VIPS, VST, WBMP, WEBM, WMV, WPG, X, XBM, XC, XCF, XPM, XPS, XV, XWD, YAML, YCBCR, YCBCRA, YUV
imagick.allow_zero_dimension_images => 0 => 0
imagick.locale_fix => 0 => 0
imagick.progress_monitor => 0 => 0
imagick.set_single_thread => 1 => 1
imagick.shutdown_sleep_count => 10 => 10
imagick.skip_version_check => 0 => 0

Please note that 198 formats are supported, but I cannot see JPEG  or JPG in this list. I am not sure if this JNG includes them.

Look at the full magick -list format list to be sure and why you get those messages. What was your exact command that you used when you got the error message.  Is your image actually JPEG and JP2000?

Please click [edit] and make sure you make a proper [mcve]. If you created and ran a docker image, show exactly how you created it and exactly how you ran it.

I am following now this lead: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/3204 This posts semms to show that JNG doesn't mean it will support JPG.

Looks like the current version of imageMagick is/was complied without Jpeg support. Ich try to find a solution for this.

In Imagemagick 7, use magick and magick identify, not convert and identify.

The problem was, that in the newer versions the jpeg support for imagemagick is now in a different package.
I set up my docker Alpine image now by loading imagemagick-dev  as well as imagemagick-jpeg and additionally also loading the matching php${PHP_SHORT}-pecl-imagick for my current phpversion e.g. php83-pecl-imagick.
RUN apk add --no-cache \
        freetype-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        jpeg-dev \
        libjpeg-turbo-dev \
        imagemagick-dev \
        imagemagick-jpeg \
        php${PHP_SHORT}-pecl-imagick 

By doing this I then have my JPEG support in my Alpine docker container:
$ magick -list format | grep JP
             see part 5 which describes the image encoding (RLE, JPEG, JPEG-LS),
             and supplement 61 which adds JPEG-2000 encoding.
      JNG* PNG       rw-   JPEG Network Graphics
      JPE* JPEG      rw-   Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format (libjpeg-turbo 3.0.3)
     JPEG* JPEG      rw-   Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format (libjpeg-turbo 3.0.3)
      JPG* JPEG      rw-   Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format (libjpeg-turbo 3.0.3)
      JPS* JPEG      rw-   Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format (libjpeg-turbo 3.0.3)
      MPO* JPEG      r--   Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format (libjpeg-turbo 3.0.3)
      PGX* PGX       rw-   JPEG 2000 uncompressed format
    PJPEG* JPEG      rw-   Joint Photographic Experts Group JFIF format (libjpeg-turbo 3.0.3)

